# can mysql find the year value of a unix timestamp?

Tags: mysql

im storing the dates that entries were posted on in the db using a standard unix timestamp.

is it possible, using only a mysql query (no php logic), to select entries that were posted in a certain year?

id like to avoid retrieving ALL entries and then using php to filter on year value. i could store the year in a separate field of course, just curious about this

Answer (score 3):

This should be what you're after:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') AS year FROM table_name WHERE my_unix_timestamp_column BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-01-01 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-12-31 23:59:59');
```

Comment: I never realized FROM_UNIXTIME accepted format arguments, nice.

Comment: You can't reference year in the WHERE clause...  It might work if you used `HAVING` instead, but then MySQL would have to work-out the YEAR for every row.

Answer (score 2):

You only want MySQL to do the hard work of extracting the year once:

```
SELECT your, columns
FROM posts
WHERE postdate BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20080101') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20090101')-1)
```

Obviously, this adapts easily to extract posts within a certain month or day or decade etc.

Comment: Note: the quotes aren't necessary; MySQL will happily handle `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(20080101)` etc. - I've no idea if this has any benefit for performance.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Ignore my own. ;)

Comment: If you accept sealea's answer, it's proper to select it as the correct one (click on the checkmark).

Answer (score 1):

maybe use the FROM_UNIXTIME() function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do that is to use a little bit of PHP to create the unix timestamp you want. If it is this year try

```
$timestamp = strtotime("January, 1, 2009");
$db->query("Select * from table where time < $timestamp");
```

This is just an example, but you will be able to quickly narrow your results and only do very minimal php logic.

Comment: He specifically said he didn't want a PHP solution.

Comment: but also said 
"id like to avoid retrieving ALL entries and then using php to filter on year value. i could store the year in a separate field of course, just curious about this"
and this is a solid solution as well that may not have been previously known.

Answer (score 0):

Depends of your mysql version. 5.1 has this neat function  [FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
    ->                      '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');


    -> '2007 30th November 10:30:59 2007'
```